# Using PHP to get JSON data using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use PHP to get JSON data using curl, however I am getting error 302, and am not getting data returned.

I can execute the curl at the command line using:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/us/Hydropotamus-1777/profile"
```

The following is the PHP script that is currently not working:

```
<?php
// Get cURL resource
$url = 'https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/Hydropotamus-1777/profile';
$curl = curl_init($url);
echo "A";
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Accept: application/json'
));
echo "B";

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo "C";
echo $resp;
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
 ?>
```

Below are a few environment details that may be helpful:

- Windows 10
- PHP 5.6.24
- Chrome browser

Comment: OK, "Not Working" is not enough, can you add curl_error($curl); to try to get an error message?

Comment: `302` is not an error, it's a redirect. Where is it trying to redirect to? Get the `Location` header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried the following and it worked for me, getting the response:

```
    <?php
// Get cURL resource
$url = 'https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/Hydropotamus-1777/profile';
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Accept: application/json'
));

// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>
```

Seems you need to disable ssl verification.

Answer (score 0):

A great tool to use is the RESTRequest class in PHP, https://gist.github.com/therealklanni/3440166 and then you can do:

```
 <?php 
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
include_once("RestRequest.php");
$url = 'https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/eu/Hydropotamus-1777/profile';

$getDataRequest = new RestRequest($dataurl, 'GET');
$getDataRequest->execute();
$data = json_decode($getDataRequest->responseBody);

echo(json_encode($data));
?>
```